# Duplicate annotation - hibernate validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations, hibernate-validator

I would like to use one hiberante validator annotation multiple times on one property.

e.g:

```
@Length(min = 10, max = 10, groups = {Lenght10Group.class})
@Length(min = 5, max = 5, groups = {Lenght5Group.class})
private String productCode;
```

I've found the following thread [Multiple annotations of the same type on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element) and tried to apply it to my application.

I created Lengths.java file:

```
public @interface Lenghts {
   Lenght[] value();
}
```

and applied it in the following way:

```
@Lenghts( {@Length(min = 10, max = 10, groups = {Lenght10Group.class}), 
           @Length(min = 5, max = 5, groups = {Lenght5Group.class}) })
private String productCode;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing? Is custom validator needed, a custom handler? Could anyone help me with this? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [@Length.List](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.List.html) which is provided by Hibernate Validator out of the box. All built-in constraints (both defined by the BV specification and additional custom constraints by Hibernate Validator) define such an @List annotation.

Comment: Sounds great! I will try it tomorrow and let you know if it helped.