# Java class with a repeated annotation. It's possible?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

It's possible to define a class with the same annotation twice?

For example, I have my @interface Annotation

```
@Annotation(value = 1)
@Annotation(value = 2)
public class MyClass{
}
```

Comment: Not yet. I'll try later, but right now I am in a design time. Thank you

Comment: As far as I remember (I had the same question some time ago) it is not possible. However, you can define another annotation `@Annotations` whose value is an array of `@Annotation`. This is done for example in JPA

Comment: It would take maybe a minute to try this out? Maybe less? Design time doesn't have to mean you uninstall javac.

Still, kudos to the answerers which went the extra step and answered the followup question ("how do I get around that limitation?").

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple annotations of the same type on one element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element)

Comment: As of Java 8 [repeating annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html) are a built-in part of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to define a Wrapper-Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface AnotationList {
    Anotation[] value () default {};
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
@AnotationList({
    @Anotation(value = 1),
    @Anotation(value = 2)
})
public class MyClass{
}
```

Comment: This is no longer (explicitly) necessary in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can define another annotation `@Annotations` whose value is an array of `@Annotation`:

```
public @interface Annotations
{
  public Annotation[] value();
}
```

It is used as

```
@Annotations
(
  {
    @Anotation(value = 1)
  , @Anotation(value = 2)
  }
)
public class MyClass {
}
```