# Hibernate: Multiple filters on an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-filters

I want to have multiple Hibernate filters on an entity, I have tried everything logical without luck and Google has come up short on this one, as has the Hibernate doc. I can't imagine that this is not possible. (Using Java 6 Hibernate 4.1.9.final)

**Currently, I have this:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORYID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORYNAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORYID")
    @OrderBy("TESTCASEID desc")
    @Filter(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER")
    private Collection<TestCase> testCases;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTCASE_NEW")
@FilterDef(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "IDS", type = "int") })
public class TestCase implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "TESTCASENAME")
    private String name;

...
}
```

I want to add a second independent filter to the Testcase class. What I am after is something like this:

```
Select ...  
  From CATEGORY INNER JOIN TESTCASE on CATEGORY.CATEGORYID = TESTCASE.CATEGORYID
 Where TESTCASE.TESTRUNID in (....)
   and TESTCASE.TESTCASENAME like '%..%'
```

**This is what I tried**

I tried adding multiple @FilterDefs to TestCase like such, but that didn't compile:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TESTCASE_NEW")
    @FilterDef(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)", 
parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "IDS", type = "int") })
    @FilterDef(name = "TESTCASE_NAME_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTCASENAME like :TESTCASE_NAME", 
parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "TESTCASE_NAME", type = "string") })

    public class TestCase implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
        private int ID;

        @Column(name = "TESTCASENAME")
        private String name;

    ...
    }
```

The Hibernate documentation led to to try something like this which complained the testrunid filter was non-existent

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
    public class Category implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "CATEGORYID")
        private int ID;

        @Column(name = "CATEGORYNAME")
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORYID")
        @OrderBy("TESTCASEID desc")
        private Collection<TestCase> testCases;
    ...
    }


       @Entity
    @Table(name = "TESTCASE_NEW")
    @FilterDef(name = "TESTCASE_FILTER", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "IDS", type = "int"), @ParamDef(name = "TESTCASE_NAME", type = "string") })
    @Filters({ @Filter(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", condition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)"), @Filter(name = "TESTCASE_NAME_FILTER", condition = "TESTCASENAME like :TESTCASE_NAME") })
    // @FilterDef(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)", parameters = { @ParamDef(name =
    // "IDS", type = "int") })
    public class TestCase implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
        private int ID;

        @Column(name = "TESTCASENAME")
        private String name;
        ...
    }
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Category> getCategories(List<Integer> testRunIDs, String category, String testCaseName)
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            session.enableFilter("FILE_TYPE_FILTER");
            if (testRunIDs != null && testRunIDs.size() != 0)
            {
                session.enableFilter("TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER").setParameterList("IDS", testRunIDs);
            }
            if (category != null && !category.equals("0") && !category.equals(""))
            {
                session.enableFilter("CATEGORY_FILTER").setParameter("CATEGORY", category);
            }

            /*
             * Hibernate wants to do an (left) outer join be default.
             * This bit of HQL is required to get it to do an inner join.
             * The query tells Hibernate to do an inner join on the testCases property inside the Category object
             */

            Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct c from Category c inner join c.testCases tc");
            List<Category> result = query.list();
            return result;

..
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: +1. the user posted what he tried.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved it actually, but thanks for the help. The solution (detailed below) is to wrap multiple @FilterDef annotations in a @FilterDef**s** annotation. Oddly enough I didn't find this anywhere or in the Hibernate doc, I saw this post ([Multiple annotations of the same type on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element)), and thought hey maybee @FilterDefs exists and it does.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTCASE_NEW")
@FilterDefs({
        @FilterDef(name = "TESTCASE_NAME_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTCASENAME like :TESTCASENAME", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "TESTCASENAME", type = "string") }),
        @FilterDef(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "IDS", type = "int") })
})
public class TestCase implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "TESTCASENAME")
    private String name;

...
}

@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORYID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORYNAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORYID")
    @OrderBy("TESTCASEID desc")
    @Filters({
            @Filter(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER"),
            @Filter(name = "TESTCASE_NAME_FILTER") })
    private Collection<TestCase> testCases;

...
}
```

In the DAO, I just turn on the ones I need

```
public List<Category> getCategories(List<Integer> testRunIDs, String category, String testCaseName)
    {
        Session session = getSession();


        if (testRunIDs != null && testRunIDs.size() != 0)
        {
            session.enableFilter("TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER").setParameterList("IDS", testRunIDs);
        }

        if (testCaseName != null)
        {
            session.enableFilter("TESTCASE_NAME_FILTER").setParameter("TESTCASENAME", testCaseName);
        }

        /*
         * Hibernate wants to do an (left) outer join be default.
         * This bit of HQL is required to get it to do an inner join.
         * The query tells Hibernate to do an inner join on the testCases property inside the Category object
         */

        Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct c from Category c inner join c.testCases tc");
        List<Category> result = query.list();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: +1. There is a reference in hibernate reference here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html#objectstate-filters I missed it too.

Comment: FYI http://learningprogramming.net/java/hibernate5/multiple-filters-on-an-entity-in-hibernate-5/