# Hibernate 3: Multiple filters with AND condition on an entity in xlm

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-filters

I want to have multiple Hibernate filters on an entity in xml config, which works with AND condition. I have found solution for annotation [Hibernate: Multiple filters on an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844220/hibernate-multiple-filters-on-an-entity) , but in xml schema missing filter-defs.
Multiple filter-def

```
<filter-def ...>
</filter-def>
<filter-def ...>
</filter-def>
```

works with OR condition.

Thanks.