# Is Java annotation order persistent?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Is Java annotation order persistent at runtime? I've checked OpenJDK 1.7.0_21 - it preserves annotations order. Can I expect that persistence on all java VMs?

Comment: I'm curious: how would that matter?

Comment: I want to know, if I can use additional annotations to specify extra arguments for earlier annotations (e.g. @DoSomething("f1") @Arg("arg1") @Arg("arg2") @DoSomething("f2") @Arg("arg2.1") @Arg("arg2.2") )

Comment: I wouldnt do that... seems confusing. What's the problem with plain `@DoSomething(value="f1", a1="arg1", a2="arg2"); @DoSomething(value="f2", a1="arg2.1", a2="arg2.2");`?

Comment: I guess that was not correct example, it was really confusing. I'm working on HTML forms validator, that loads all validation requerements from method and field annotations. So validator annotations could look like this:

@Field("username") @NotEmpty @ErrorMessage("Requred Field")
@Validator(controller.users.NewUsernameValidator.class) @ErrorMessage("This username is already taken")
public String getUsername() ...

But that will work only if annotation order is persistent, otherwise, I'll have to put errorMessage string to every annotation as parameter.

Comment: Are you trying to redo JSR 303 and its implementations from scratch? Look at the Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Strange, that I missed Hibernate Validator, when I was looking for suitable validator. Thanks for hint.

Comment: JSR 303 has other implementations too, and some Java web frameworks can integrate with JSR 303 to allow both client and server-side validation from the annotations.  I used a module for Apache Wicket.  Spring and Spring MVC supports it too.

Comment: Duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067074/java-annotations-reflection-ordering/30222541#30222541

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "persistent". I think you might have meant something implied in the question, so here's few Q&A:

**Is the annotation order persistent?**
Yes, it's written in the `.class` file in an order that doesn't change.

**Does the annotations order in the `.class` file reflect the annotations order in the source code?**
Yes. If you compile your code...

```
@Column(length = 256)
@NotBlankConstraint(message = "The application title must be set.")
@Size(min = 1, max = 256, message = "The application title must be set and not longer than 250 characters.")
private String title;
```

and check with `javap -v`:

```
 #67 = Utf8               Ljavax/validation/constraints/Size;
...
private java.lang.String title;
  descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
  flags: ACC_PRIVATE
  RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
    0: #50(#62=I#63)
    1: #64(#65=s#66)
    2: #67(#68=I#69,#70=I#63,#65=s#71
```

If you change the order of the annotations, the order in the byte code will change as well. Tested with OpenJDK 1.8.0_121, but I think that's the case for earlier JDKs too.

**Is the order from the bytecode kept by the `getAnnotations()` method?**
Yes, from what I can see, it is consistently returning the same order as is in the byte code in the `.class` file.

**Is `getAnnotations()` guaranteed to reflect the bytecode annotations order in the future?**
No. As replied by the other answer, this behavior is not documented, so can't be relied on in a publicly available library.
However, there are [subtle signs that the order should be kept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-) somehow.

Now to your purpose,
**If it was guaranteed, should I use the order to have some annotation apply to some previous annotations?**
That's a matter of taste, but I would say that most Java programmers wouldn't like that. It wouldn't be much intuitive and readable code. I would suggest to group the annotations such like

```
@ValidationGroup(
     validators = { @NotNull, @NotEmpty },
     message = "User name must be filled."
)
public String getUsername();
```

The problem with this is that you can't have an array of "any annotation", and since there's no inheritance for annotations, this can't be done (Java 1.8). So various frameworks resort to what Bean Validation uses - see it's concept of groups.

Lastly, I'd second to Eric's comment to check JSR 303, it's quite well done and also integrated into many other libraries like RestEasy.

Comment: Part of your example doesn't look possible: `validators = { @NotNull, @NotEmpty }`  Is this an oversight, or can you provide a definition of the `validators()` member that permits this sort of usage?

Comment: @GlennLane, you're right. I'll fix with better example.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotations--) API says that it returns all annotations present on this element. It says nothing about the order in which these annotations are returned

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30222541/810109 - regarding to it the annotations are retrieved in a **guaranteed** order.

Answer (score -5):

In Java 7 and lower, you cannot have multiple annotations of the same type on an element.  You  can make them part of the value of another annotation:

```
// JSR 303
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp="\\w{8,14}"),
    @Pattern(regexp=".*Z.*")
})
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
```

Java 8 will be relaxing this.  See [Oracle's bug tracker](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7151010). This was discussed at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element).

Comment: This didn't answer the question of whether or not order matters. If you have `public void method(@Foo @Bar String str)`, it would be nice to assume that if i make it to processing bar that it meets all the criteria of foo.