# Java Annotations Reflection Ordering

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

When accessing Annotations defined on a Field via Reflection (i.e using the `getDeclaredAnnotations() : Annotation[]` method) does the Java 6 or 7 specification make any guarantees about the order in which the Annotations are returned. I have examined the relevant java docs but can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Comment: I have wondered this myself especially with java 8 @Repeatable

Comment: I was asking myself the same question - I could not find any clear statement so far. Any news on this?

Comment: @Adam Gent, @mkurz: at least for repeatable annotations, there are some clear words within the specification, I’ve assembled them together. They even allow a conclusion about the original question regarding `getDeclaredAnnotations()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java annotation order persistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756291/is-java-annotation-order-persistent)

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756291/is-java-annotation-order-persistent/42126227#42126227

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That’s indeed a bit underspecified. Let’s start with the Java 8 feature of repeatable annotations as there are some bits about it:

[JLS §9.7.5. Multiple Annotations of the Same Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.5):

> The implicitly declared annotation is called the *container annotation*, and the multiple annotations of type `T` which appeared in the context are called the *base annotations*. The elements of the (array-typed) `value` element of the container annotation are all the base annotations in the left-to-right order in which they appeared in the context.

So the container will provide the repeated annotations in order.

Additionally, the documentation of [`AnnotatedElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) specifies:

> For an invocation of `get[Declared]AnnotationsByType( Class < T >)`, the order of annotations which are directly or indirectly present on an element *E* is computed as if indirectly present annotations on *E* are directly present on *E* in place of their container annotation, in the order in which they appear in the value element of the container annotation.

Putting these two together, it implies that repeated annotations like `@Foo(1) @Foo(2) @Foo(3)` are stored like you had written `@FooContainer({@Foo(1), @Foo(2), @Foo(3)})` and the latter, regardless of how it was originally created, will be treated by `getDeclaredAnnotations()` like directly present annotations of that order.

So the answer for repeated annotations is that the order will be the “left-to-right order in which they appeared”.

---

But there is another conclusion we can draw from the documentation of `AnnotatedElement`. Since it states that the order of annotations is computed as if indirectly present annotations are directly present in place of their container annotation, it implies that if you write `@Foo(1) @FooContainer({@Foo(2), @Foo(3)})` or `@FooContainer({@Foo(1), @Foo(2)}) @Foo(3)`, the order will be the same as the elements of the container will replace it just as had you written `@Foo(1) @Foo(2) @Foo(3)`.

It’s interesting, [how that is achieved](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getDeclaredAnnotationsByType-java.lang.Class-):

> If annotations of the annotation type annotationClass are found to be both directly and indirectly present, then `getDeclaredAnnotations()` will get called to determine the order of the elements in the returned array.

This implementation note is the first indicator within the entire documentation that `getDeclaredAnnotations()` has a reliable order. It is used to determine the order that is required to fulfill the contract described above.

So the answer is, yes, `getDeclaredAnnotations()` provides the annotations in a guaranteed order, but that information is not directly attached to the documentation of the method itself.

This is derived from the Java 8 documentation, but since Java 6 and 7 reached their end-of-life now and won’t change, the fact that the observed behavior of the their implementation matches the behavior that is guaranteed at least for Java 8, might be enough to rely on it.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your well-presented and comprehensive answer.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! That's the first statement at all I could find which clearly and logically says in which order annotations are retrieved via `getDeclaredAnnotations()` - and I have done quite some research already... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you can rely on a subtle hint not directly stating the contract of the method to keep the order. If it was the case that it's "someone just forgot to mention it in the docs", this would already be fixed.  

Until it's set in stone, coding against an assumption that it will stay so in the future may break your annotations-based feature.

Comment: @Ondra Žižka: there are tons of documentation flaws that haven’t been fixed for years. Besides that, it simply makes no sense to have no guaranteed order for annotations in `getDeclaredAnnotations()`, but an explicit guaranty for repeated annotations. But you are invited to open an RFE for the documentation.

Comment: I agree with you. But seriously - until it's documented as the method's contract, it's not usable in enterprise applications or non-experimental library. See [BVAL-248](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/BVAL/issues/BVAL-248)

Comment: @OndraŽižka did you talk to the OpenJDK guys already? Any news?

Comment: @mkurz, I did, no reply yet. Bumping the topic, hold on.

Comment: I talked to one of OpenJDK contributors and he said there should be no problem making this official. So we will create a "request for specification" and there is some chance it could land in the JDK.next.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Was the "request for specification" created already? Can you provide a link? Thanks!