# Custom Annotation not working

Tags: java, annotations

I have created a custom annotation and it's working for 1'st program but not for 2'nd. I am not able to figure out what's wrong in the second one. Can anyone please explain:

Below Program is working:

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="last")
public void Calendar() {
      //Some Code goes Here.
}
```

Below Program not working:

```
@Event(startTime="22-Jun-2013")
@Event(startTime="22-June-2013", duration="21 Hours")
public void Calendar() {
      //Some Code goes Here.
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the same annotation twice on the same field, type, method, etc. [Here's a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element)

Comment: At least not until [JDK 8: Repeating Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html). Not sure if that would work for you, though.