# transaction annotation or xml

Tags: java, spring, transactions, transactional

In my project, I need to process more databases in one transaction.

1: using annotation, this reports error "duplicate annotation"

```
public class TransactionalService {

@Transactional("order")
@Transactional("account")
public void processTwoDatabases(String name) { ... }

}
```

xml segment as follow

```
<bean id="transactionManager1"
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <qualifier value="order"/>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager2" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
       <qualifier value="account"/>
</bean>
```

2: But using xml, it works fine:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice1" transaction-manager="transactionManager1">
    <!-- 定义方法的过滤规则 -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="process*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"
                   rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution (* com.service.impl.*.*(..))" id="services1"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice1" pointcut-ref="services1"/>
</aop:config>


<tx:advice id="txAdvice2" transaction-manager="transactionManager2">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="process*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"
                   rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution (* com.service.impl.*.*(..))" id="services2"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice2" pointcut-ref="services2"/>
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow multiple annotations of the same type on the same element, unless the annotation is (meta)-annotated with `@Repeatable`: [Multiple annotations of the same type on one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554112/multiple-annotations-of-the-same-type-on-one-element)

But `Transactional` is not (meta)-annotated with `@Repeatable`, hence only one instance of `@Transactional` is allowed on a type or method.

You have to use XML in this case.

But please note that you do not get one transaction. You actually get two different transactions, one per transaction manager.

Also, you don't specify any datasource in your transaction manager definitions, so they both use the same datasource (and the same database).

To actually have one transaction, you may need XA Transaction support. Here are some links:

1. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html
2. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html
3. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

Comment: I want to rollback all transactions if any one of the two transaction failed.  In my way ,the two transations as follows:   <br/> 
 `(1) transaction1 start `                       
   `(2) transaction2 start `              
    `(3) my business logic code `
     `(4) transaction 2 end  `
    `(5)   transaction1  end `  
 so any exception is thrown between  1-4  ，the two transaction will rollback. the only flew is the exception thrown between (4) and (5), only outer transaction will rollback 
 ,but inner transaction will commit.`@Roman Puchkovskiy `