# Kotlin repeatable @annotations don't work on jdk-8

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I have declared a repeatable annotation `@Parameter` in [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) as below:

```
@Repeatable
annotation class Parameter(val name: String);
```

but when I use it as below the compiler reports an Error:

> **Only annotations with SOURCE retention can be repeated on JVM version before 1.8**

```
@Parameter("foo")
@Parameter("bar")
fun repeat() = 1;
```

I'm sure I'm working with `jdk-8` in [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin). and the option `jvmTarget` also is set to `1.8` for `kotlin-1.1.2` gradle plugin.

**Q:** Why it doesn't works fine?

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions{
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try this approach instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554144/3763032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, **Kotlin** compiler currently targets the `JDK 1.6` class file format. This means that, on **Java**, it can't write multiple annotations to the class file.

While conceptually **Kotlin** supports multiple annotations, until there's proper `1.8` targeting, it can't do so because of the output restrictions.

Comment: hi, but the error message only says if the jvm target is **1.8** you can using repeatable annotation. so how to fix the compiler error rather than using a `SOURCE` retention for a repeatable annotation?

Comment: It looks like we don't have any other options now, except for container annotations.

Comment: sir, maybe you are right. but in jdk8 I can using repeatable annotation by [@Repeatable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Repeatable.html).

Comment: Ye, I know, but unfortunately it doesn't work for **Kotlin** yet.

Comment: sir, if you are sure that don't work for [tag:kotlin]. do you having some reference or conversation for that?

Comment: That's the only one I've managed to find: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12794

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible with Kotlin. There is a bug opened, please feel free to vote for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12794

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just use the "long form" of the annotation.

Follow the end of this thread:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/issue-with-repeated-java-8-annotations/1667/11

Answer (score 0):

Check the Kotlin compiler settings in IntelliJ. IntelliJ doesn't use gradle to build and run your project by default. It uses the IDEA Kotlin plugin.

Comment: thanks, sir. but it's not an intellij problem. I run the command `gradle check` also reports this compiler error.